# Converting microservice to Knative

Tags: istio, knative

Knative is currently in alpha. I need to develop a service, so that when knative is released the conversion is straightforward.

What type of kubernetes deployed service would most easily be converted to knative? I also will be leveraging Istio. So just want to make this as simple as possible.  (Also any estimates on when knative will be released or where I should check for that information).

Answer (score 1):

The latest release of Knative, [v0.7, is v1beta1](https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/tag/v0.7.0) not alpha and as far as I'm aware the API's are now very close to how they will be in v1.0.

We currently use Knative v0.7 and I would suggest developing the apps using that until v1.0 is released.

R.E. Knative v1.0 release, I would keep an eye on these two github milestones: https://github.com/knative/serving/milestone/18 & https://github.com/knative/serving/milestone/24 . The latter milestone is due on August 06 2019 & currently "The ambition of 0.8 [this milestone] is to be a release candidate for a "v1" of serving."